# How can I add file names as the first line in AWK command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to get the ninth column from multiple files in one single file using paste and awk , this worked with this code:

```
paste <(awk '{FS="\t"}{OFS="\t"}{ a[FNR] = (a[FNR] ? a[FNR] FS : "") $9 } END { for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i] }' $(ls -1v */groups.txt))>file.txt
```

now I want the first row to be the parent directory  for each of these files
how could this be done?

I tried:

```
paste <(awk '{FS="\t"}{OFS="\t"}}BEGIN{var=$FILENAME; split (var,b,/\//); print b[3]}{ a[FNR] = (a[FNR] ? a[FNR] FS : "") $9 } END { for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i] }' $(ls -1v */groups.txt))>file.txt
```

but it prints an empty line at the beginning of the file

Comment: Post input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want the parent directory for each of these files you could use something like:

```
for file in */groups.txt; do echo ${file%%/*} ; done
```

Comment: I want to add the parent directory to the output file, so that I know each column is coming from which directory @JFS31

Comment: So you want the output from your first command with the addition of the Parent Directory? It would be really nice if you could post how your expected output should look like.